# PHP if mysqli query statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am in the process of creating a website that displays a group of questions, however my problem is checking if the user has answered the question or not, and if they have, display an “Answered” label.

However the currently, It is displayed the “Answered” Label for each and every question, even if the answer is not in the submissions table. Any help would be appreciated.

```
while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
  if($data[0] != null){
  echo('
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5">
    <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-default"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-codepen fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        ');
        if($result4 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM submissions where teamID='$teamName' and questionID='$data[0]' and status='correct'")){
          echo "Answered";
        } else{
          echo "Not Answered";
        }

        echo ('
        <h4>'.$data[6].' - <small><i>'.$data[8].' points</i></small></h4>
        <p>'.$data[7].'</p>
        <a href="question.php?id='.$data[0].'" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">View Question </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ');} else{
    echo "No More Questions";
  }
}
```

I know I am making a basic or stupid error here, So any help appreciated.

Comment: you forget mysqli_query("")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Mysql query to find number of answers for particular question.
$answercount = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM submissions where teamID='$teamName' and questionID='$data[0]' and status='correct'");
$answercount = mysqli_num_rows($answercount);

//PHP code
if($answercount>0){
    echo "Answered";
} else{
    echo "Not Answered";
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response, Greatly appreciated, I like the method you used, but still no luck with achieving what I am looking for. With your code, I am receiving all the question as "Not Answered".

Comment: Have you replaced the $con with your $mysqi in the mysqi_query function?

Comment: Hello, Indeed I have, I am using the varable $mysqli, instead of $con. Its like its not actually using the query and checking, because when I echo out the query, it shows the correct information  `SELECT * FROM submissions where teamID='Admin' and questionID='121' and status='correct' 
Not Answered
Section 1 - 100 points

2016 cyberlympics questions

View Question
SELECT * FROM submissions where teamID='Admin' and questionID='129' and status='correct' `

Comment: What output your are getting from the mysqi_num_rows function in our code. Does it gives '0' for Everytime?

Comment: When you are executing above query in MySQL workbench or phpmyadmin, does it give correct result?

Comment: Sorry, I have found the solution, It was a typo error on my part, using your solution, Thank you for your help, I will post my final solution.

Comment: Ok that's great you have got final solution from my help. Your welcome.. :)

Answer (score 0):

you forget `mysqli_query("")`

```
if ($result4 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM submissions where teamID='$teamName' and questionID='$data[0]' and status='correct'")) {
  echo "Answered";
} else {
  echo "Not Answered";
}
```

Comment: Sorry I had that in, but removed it to test something, However this still did not resolve the issue. I have updated the code in the original question.